# List value is missing while receiving a messgae in NServiceBus

Tags: c#, nservicebus

My message object has a list and some properties. Say List MyList. I send this message to a queue. NSBHandler receives this message. But MyList is missing in that received message. All other properties exist.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Regin Thangaraj

Comment: Are you declaring the property as List or IList?

Comment: I have declared as List.

Comment: List of what?  Is that class in your messages assembly as well?

Comment: Can you post the class that is implementing IMessage up?

Answer (score 4):

If you've used an auto property and you've done it like this:

```
public List<Stuff> MyListOfStuff { get; private set; }
```

Then NServiceBus will skip it on serialization as it knows that on deserilization it will won't be able to set the property with the private setter..